# Find all solutions when two functions are the same (same result)

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

Can anybody help me find solutions for $x$ when: $$y_1 = y_2$$
and equations are (for example):
$$y_1 = \frac{(x^2+x)}{2} \;; \;y_2 = \frac{(x^2+19x-12)}{2}$$

By solving it "brute force" I can tell some of the solutions are:

1. $$y_1(5)=y_2(2)=15$$
2. $$y_1(15)=y_2(9)=120$$
3. $$?\ \ \ \ ? \ \ \ ?$$

Thank you!

Comment: So, to be clear, when $y_1$ and $y_2$ have the same output, even if $x$ might not be the same... An interesting question. Experience might suggest a clever parameterization, if not brute force, but this is just a guess. Nonetheless, good luck.

Comment: In short, you want to solve diophantine equations (for two variables). [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) . It might help a little.

Comment: Wouldn't Diophantine equations only suffice for integer solutions? What about real values of $x$, which I feel is more in line with what OP wants.

Comment: There many confusing things here. With usual interpretation we have $y_1=y_2$ iff $x=\frac 2 3$ but you are allowing different values of $x$ on LHS and RHS. Also it is not clear  if you are looking for integer solutions. There is a continuum of solutions if you don't restrict  to integer values of $x$.

Comment: Hi Kavi, Yes I am looking of course integer solution, sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

For integers $a,b$, we wish to solve $$\frac{a^2+a}2=\frac{b^2+19b-12}2\implies\left(a+\frac12\right)^2-\frac14=\left(b+\frac{19}2\right)^2-\frac{361}4-12$$ so $$\left(b+\frac{19}2\right)^2-\left(a+\frac12\right)^2=102\implies (a+b+10)(b-a+9)=2\cdot3\cdot17$$ from which only eight possible combinations exist.

Comment: tnx for the hint, but can you please drop some more details, so I can actually conclude for next similar problem? Also as what I can see this would also require checking for each of them, or I am missing something?

Comment: @Jovan The cases are $(a+b+10,b+a+9)=(1,102),(2,51),(3,34),(6,17),(17,6),(34,3),(51,2),(102,1)$. You'll need to solve all of them.

Comment: thank you for your comments, how come that two example pairs are (5,2), (15,9) not in the list?

Comment: @Jovan Because $(2,5)$ corresponds to $(a,b)$ *not* $(a+b+10,b-a+9)$ (minus sign typo in comment above). You will need to solve these simultaneous equations - albeit not difficult.

Comment: TNX! Based on which theorem you reconstruct equations and than you got these pairs to be solved? There is no possibility to derive some general "formulation" which excludes solving all this? I mean there is no other solution, which excludes testing various cases?

Comment: It really depends on the context and the type of question you're answering - it's impossible to say in general. But a good tactic when handling multivariate quadratics is to complete the square.